# Finding the "top" of a mesh representing the terrain

Tags: unity, mesh

I'm generating a low-poly mesh for terrain, and for a given world coordinate I'd like to know where the "ground" is.

My game uses fairly standard infinite terrain - I generate noise values for world coordinates and use them to generate this mesh procedurally. This is done in chunks of 16x16.

I'm planning to begin decorating the terrain with plants and such and I need a good way to determine how high the ground is.

So for example, if I want a rock at `x: 5, z: 5`, what's the best/most efficient way to figure out the "height" of the ground at that location?

I've considered trying to inspect the mesh vertices, or maybe using a top-down ray cast and picking the collision point, but I'm looking for advice before I begin.

[image]

I've tried the raycast method, and it works perfectly, I'm just not sure how efficient that is. I'll profile if any alternatives seem worth comparing.

Comment: How is the noise converted to a mesh? Seems like you should be able to use the same algorithm to calculate the height based on the noise value for the given position without needing to do any ray casting.

Comment: Do you generate a heightfield as a texture or 2D array of values during your terrain generation? If so, that could serve as a convenient lookup source.

Comment: I'm building the mesh directly, [my code is based on this](https://github.com/Syomus/ProceduralToolkit/blob/master/Examples/LowPolyTerrain/LowPolyTerrainGenerator.cs#L54). That was my first thought, using the vertices, but I'm quite sure the best way to convert those vertices into world space, especially since I need to take into the angles.